# Typing a function that filters an arrayTypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics

I am trying to get items from an array filtered using a supplied constructor using TypeScript.  I have not been able to solve the scenario using TypeScript.  Am I close?  Thanks!

```ts
type IConstructor = new (...args: any[] ) => {};
class Apple extends Thing { ... }
class Orange extends Thing { ... }
const items: Thing[] = [
    new Apple();
    new Orange();
];

let apples = getItemsOfType( Apple );  //Hopefully using the function like this

//Type 'Thing[]' is not assignable to type 'TypeOf[]'.
//Type 'Thing' is not assignable to type 'TypeOf'.
//'TypeOf' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Thing'.
//=================================================================================
getItemsOfType<TypeOf extends IConstructor>( TypeConstructor: TypeOf ): TypeOf[] {
    return items.filter( item => {
        return item instanceof TypeConstructor;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you were pretty close. Somewhat generic version would look like that:

```ts
function getItemsOfType<T extends IConstructor>(ctor: T): InstanceType<T>[] {
    return items.filter( (item): item is InstanceType<T> => {
        return item instanceof ctor;
    });
}
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wQAPjw)

You have to [explicitly annotate](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5101) `filter` cb function as type guard to hint typescript about it's 'type-level' meaning.

Or a more generic version with stronger type constraints and no implicit dependency on free variable `items` inside the function:

```ts
function getItemsOfType<
    T extends unknown[], 
    U extends IConstructor<ArrayElement<T>>
>(items: T, ctor: U): InstanceType<U>[] {
    return items.filter( (item): item is InstanceType<U> => {
        return item instanceof ctor;
    });
}
```

[playgroud link](https://tsplay.dev/N5E1dN)